# law of exponents Sympy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I am using Sympy library python on jupyter notebook I want to do law of exponents and get the correct results instead I am getting the input returned not the actual answer I was expecting here is the code

```
    from sympy import *
    x = symbols('x')
    y = symbols('y')

    axis = x**3
    why = y**2

    display(axis*why)

    // this is that code I am getting x^3*x^2 which I don't want it
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the code that you tried? I just tried and it works fine giving `x**3*y**2`

Comment: I know but that's not what I want to get .

Comment: @treashureprogramming but what do you want ?

Comment: @treashureprogramming What is your expected answer on this problem ?